# Positivity of a distance on $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\text{SO}(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A,B \in  \text{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Define $s_1=AA^T,s_2=BB^T$.

Write
$$
\text{det}(ts_1-s_2) = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)
$$
where each $\lambda_i$ is positive and they satisfy $\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots\lambda_n=1$.

Now, suppose that $\lambda_i=1$ for every $1 \le i \le n$.

Why does this imply $s_1=s_2$?

*Comment:*

This question comes from an attempt to see directly why the distance on $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\text{SO}(n)$ induced by the unique $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$-invariant metric is positive.

(It turns out that when representing elements $m=A\cdot \text{SO}(n)$ via $s=\sigma(m)=AA^T$, then up to a constant multiple, one has
$$
dist(s_1,s_2) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\log\lambda_i)^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$

(For further details see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108280/left-invariant-metric-on-sln/109951#109951) by Robert Bryant)

*Edit:*

Denote $C=A^{-1}BB^TA^{-T}$.

As observed in the answer below,

$$ \det(tI-C)= (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)\cdots(t-\lambda_n), $$

so the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $C$ are exactly $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$.

Since $C$ is orthogonally diagonalizable, there exist $P \in O_n$ s.t

$$ PCP^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n).$$

Thus, the closer $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ to $I$, the closer $C$ is to $I$. Explicitly:

$$ \| C-I\|=\| P^{-1}\Lambda P-I\|=\| P^{-1}(\Lambda-I)P\|=\|\Lambda-I \|$$

or, by noting that $C \in Psym_n$, and hence has a unique symmetric logarithm,

$$ d(C,I)=\| \log C\|=\| \log (P^{-1}\Lambda P)\|=\| P^{-1}(\log \Lambda)P\|=\|\log \Lambda \|=d(\Lambda,I),$$ where $\| \|$ is the standard Euclidean (Frobenius) norm, and we endow $Psym_n$ with its left translation metric).

So, indeed $\|\log \Lambda \|$ can serve as a reasonable measure for the distance between $s_1,s_2$.

Comment: Since $ts_1-s_2$ is symmetric and thus diagonalizable, by the end result you know $P(ts_1-s_2)P^{-1}=t-I$. The desired result thus follow from a comparision of the coefficient of $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am not sure how to deduce the exact claim you are implying though. (I was able to deduce something weaker, please see my edited part in the question). What am I missing?

Comment: Do you know the determinant of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: maybe one way to see it, consider s1

Comment: I am still not sure what exactly do you mean in your suggested approach. However, a nice solution (which seems somewhat in the spirit of your argument) was added below.

Comment: Sorry as there is no internet in JFK. I meant the following, it is clear that the.

Comment: Lambas are the eigenvalues. So they do not change after diagonalization. Then the left hand side can be viewed as t minus A like usual linear algebra, and you are diagonalize A. This A is nothing but s1 inverse times s2. I claim t minus the diagonalization you get of A coincide with the diagonalization you wrote here. Expand and compare coefficients of t give you the desired result. Note that we are okay since det s1 is one.

Comment: Yes I do think it is essentially the same.

Comment: But I do think robert byrant meant lambais are eigenvalues of t minus A. So they cannot appear in clusters in a term in the diagonalization. This may explain why he want the product of lambda I to be 1, since s1, s2 are from Sl matrices

Comment: Actually, I also wondered about that. But then I deduced that $\text{det}(ts_1-s_2) = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)$ implies the product of the $\lambda_i$ is $1$, by taking the limit of both sides when $t \to 0$ (and recalling $s_2 \in SL_n$.

Comment: I thought about this as well. However it is not clear to me how to compute $\lambda s_1+(1-\lambda)s_2, \lambda\in [0,1]$ in general. I thought Bryant is referring to some special curve in $SL_{n}$. Now I see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $A^{-T}=(A^T)^{-1}$. Then
$$
\det(ts_1-s_2)=\det(A)\det(tI-A^{-1}BB^TA^{-T})\det(A^T)=\det(tI-A^{-1}BB^TA^{-T}).
$$
So, the given conditions mean that all eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $A^{-1}BB^TA^{-T}$ are equal to $1$. Hence $A^{-1}BB^TA^{-T}=I$, i.e. $AA^T=BB^T$.